# Resolving a poor search on run-on tokens in a query

Tags: c#, token, search-engine

A little personal project of mine is to blindly produce a search engine from scratch without using any outside sources. This is mostly for a learning experience and I haven't had much trouble up until now, where I have both a dilemma and a tough problem.

Observe this case:

Suzy wants to search for "fuzzy bears". This is fine, functions as well as it can. However, Suzy screws up and types "fuzzybears". Right now, my search algorithm breaks down since this is interpreted as a single token, and not multiple tokens. Any case or combination of words that has even one occurrence of such a run on term, or glued tokens, causes a poor search result.

For scope, this is something I am writing using a combination of C# and T-SQL.

I've tried multiple solutions, but nothing has really come from them. Firstly, I used a List to take the terms and create variations, but this was much too slow to my liking and required a lot more memory than I feel it should need.

I wanted to save search queries to a database for statistics and maybe to learn more about organically growing the algorithm, so maybe a way to handle these glued tokens in SQL could be a solution, but I have no clue how to start with something like that unless I used a cursor or some other slow solution.

I could take searches, save them to my database, create different combinations where some tokens are glued, and then have those glued tokens as terms to hit on? The issue with this solution is it takes up quite a bit of space and I won't always need these strings since spelling errors like this aren't all too common.

Mainly, what I need is speed. It doesn't really have to be pretty, but if it's fast and accurate then I'm happy even if it takes up a lot of disk space.

Not asking for solutions here, but if anyone can point me in a direction I can go or it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about using a dictionary of words and compare the typed string with it?

Comment: I think he's already tried that: "Firstly, I used a List to take the terms and create variations", that didn't work.

Comment: Well, what i understand there is he is generating it in runtime. What i mean is  creating a preloaded list of,for example, English words and combinations of them (this may be a lot of work, but should be done only once). Then, searching the tokens there should be fast I think

Comment: Yes, the issue here is that the tokens coming in are already glued together. I can certainly create variations of the terms given, but unless I know where each word starts and ends in the glued token, it doesn't do much.

Hence it being slow. I would need to break down each unrecognized glued token and compare each substring of the larger string to a dictionary, which is inefficient but accurate. 

What I would really love is a space efficient way to predict such glued tokens, but I don't think that is possible.

Comment: If your search was based on `Contains`,you could separate the words easyly? But of course was just a quick thought, the provided answer seems a better solution to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this approach: since spaces, punctuation, and anything similar would screw up a search like this, remove all of those, convert to a common case (I prefer lowercase, but pick what you prefer), and then tokenize based on syllables, using roughly the same set of division rules as for hyphenating English words.

So, to search for answers that contain "Consider this approach:", you reduce the phrase to "considerthisapproach" and then tokenize as "con","sid","er","this","ap","proach".  If con and sid and er appear next to each other, and in that order, you've found the word "consider".

This approach can be adapted for statistical matching too, so e.g. if at least 85% of syllables are found in the correct order, you consider it a close match, and maybe order the results by match % so more meaningful matches are at the top.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution! Thank you! However, my current search algorithm is based on the Levenshtein Distance formula, do you think it could work in conjunction with your solution?

Comment: Depends on the details of your implementation, but I think it could be adapted, and possibly even work better in conjunction with Levenshtein distances, since those operate at a "word" level, without defining what a word is.  For example, if you are trying to match "Consider this approach:" with the typo-filled "Condider rhis appeoach:", you might break it into syllables and do L-distance on mismatched syllables only, for fewer L-distances to compute, or you could rely on L-distances for everything and rank space as a zero-cost change (con sid er changes into consider by removing two spaces).